# Ubuntu desktop download refused by Safari

Tags: boot, downloads

“ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso.download” probably not valid file-
it is written on desktop upon attempt of instalation,
I'm trying to make bootable USB (to install ubuntu on old MacBook) and this is the point where I stucked.
Tnx4 help in advance !

Comment: This is a mac problem with it wanting to extract iso files. Try chrome

Comment: askubuntu.com  is all about support for Ubuntu and its official flavours. But you have obviously a problem with MacOS and the Safari browser, which is not Ubuntu-related at all. Please consider asking your question in a forum dedicated to MacOS support.

Comment: Consider https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/963/518394